# ViewPager flips instead of scrolls when paging through onClick

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented a ViewPager in my app, and aside from the swipe paging, I have buttons for "Next" and "Back", with a simple onClick method with the only line being a setCurrentItem for the ViewPager.

While the paging animation is completely smooth during swiping, it is more or less instantaneous (just flips instead of scrolling) when I click Next or Back. There is no visible "scrolling" motion, or sometimes barely visible, however not even close to smooth. It does not hurt the usability of the app in any way, since the transition still happens immediately, but visually it looks a lot less appealing, and the user experience suffers.

Now, I suspect it has something to do with the app drawing the next View and therefore "skipping" the animation. My instantiateItem uses LayoutInflater and a simple switch statement to inflate each view (4 pages at most), and I am loading custom ListViews inside each case in the switch statement. The custom ListViews are at most 3 items long, with a TextView and an ImageView in each row (ImageView resource is 5kb in size). To me it seems this amount of objects should not be reason enough to slow down the paging animation.

Aside from that, I also have a custom background assigned to my app in styles.xml, and this is the background used through every activity (160kb in size).

Those are the only things that I think could be slowing down the app, since the onClick method contains only one line (setCurrentItem), so nothing aside from going to the next view is happening in the app, and the instantiateItem is the simplest implementation of the method possible that I know of.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the ViewPager's setOffScreenPageLimit to 4, which I thought would pre-load the views and eliminate any loading in between paging, but in the end setting it to 0 seemed to make the thing slightly more likely to show at least a frame of animation
- Optimizing the custom ListViews by using convertView to reuse old views, while it did result in more of the animation being shown, it still wasn't completely smooth, varying from "almost perfect animation" to "instant flip"
- Removing the custom background, which together with the above two fixes lead to an almost good enough solution, but still resulted in flips every few steps.

The tinkering described above leads me to believe it has something to do with the views being loaded, but I've not found a good solution for pre-loading these to the desirable effect.
Knowing my newbie programming skills, I know there is a sure fire way to solve this without resorting to gimping the design of the app itself, but reading through the documentation, Stack Overflow questions, Googling for advice, I've just ran out of places to look to.

**To sum up this probably too verbally descriptive post my main questions are:**

- Is there a way to ensure the animation of the ViewPager is executed smoothly? A separate thread perhaps? As I understand though, UI stuff should only be on the main thread, where it already is, and nothing else aside from the view loading is executed anywhere in the code when paging.
- Should I be using a different way to load the pages? Would Fragments help?

Thank you for any advice.

ps. The lack of code is due to the methods in question being the most basic implementations possible, but I will provide the code if necessary.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the instantiation/preloading of new items, are you destroying views that aren't being used to free up memory?

Comment: Yes, I am destroying views. Now that you've mentioned memory, I checked the logs a bit, and it seems that every times I page through the ViewPager completely from left to right _and_ completely back, there is a garbage collector firing off, freeing up around 1.5 to 2mb of memory (with no background, it is around 900kb). This seems substantial, could it be the root if all problems? Reading up on it, the "heap dump" should contain some clues, should I attach it here?

Comment: Could very well be the cause of your misery :) It might help others, to add your heap dump, you will want to look for memory leaks

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15809701/dump.hprof <- here it is. Though I have no sense of what is what, and the app in question does not appear among the memory leakers. Though it most likely is the reason, since to me it makes no sense that scrolling through a 4 page ViewPager with tiny ListViews should force 2mb garbage collection every time you go through the pager.

Comment: look for static references to images, and use .recycle() on images you nonlonger need. These are the most difficult errors in my opinion